# Alias with input

Tags: command-line, alias

pretty new to linux and trying to create an alias that runs a python file here's how it goes.

```
alias search=("cd /home/SET && python3 /home/SET/search.py")
```

The only problem is that "search.py" takes and input and it can't be provided due to the parentheses *(because I don't wanna change directory to /home/kali/SET Everytime i run it.)*, So is there anything can i do about it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We are sorry, Kali Linux is off-topic. You can use https://forums.kali.org/ but expect them to be very harsh: Kali is intended for experienced GNU/Linux users and users are expected to fix their own problems and only when that fails to have them ask a question with a well-documented problem.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following function should do what you want:

```
search(){   
cd /home/SET
python3 /home/SET/search.py "$@"
cd -
}
```

You should execute the command `search` and give it as many parameters as you want. They'll all be passed to python script.
As you can see in the function, I'm getting into the directory /home/set, executing the command and getting back to where I was before the execution. But first you need to execute that function definition in a shell then you can use it (Copy the code I provided and paste it in the terminal). And the way you use it is just like how you'd use an alias. Example:

`search arg_1 arg_2`

Comment: The only problem is i have the parentheses so i can run the command in a different shell environment not affecting my main shell, because I don't wanna change my directory everytime i run this command.

Comment: If you don't want to cd into that directory, then you should include the full path to the program. That way you preserve your current working directory and execute the script at the same time. `cd /home/SET` part of the command is unnecessary. All you have to do is set the following alias:
`alias search="python3 /home/SET/search.py"`
I'm editing the answer now. Check it out

Comment: I thought of that, but "search.py" has a config that it scans for and it must be in the directory you are executing the command from.

Comment: Then you should use a function instead of an alias. I cant put a code in the comment. Please check out my answer again

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it working.

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad to be of some help